# Windows Server 2022 - Port 445/TCP Not Accessible from other machines

Tags: windows, network-share, server-message-block

I have two physical copies of Windows Server 2022 running, both machines have firewalls completely disabled.   I have enabled file and folder sharing on both machines on the domain, private and public levels.   Let's call the first server \\ServerA and the non working server \\ServerB.   I can browse to \\ServerA and see any shared folders on that system, both locally and from other Windows clients.   However on ServerB, I can see shared folders by browsing \\ServerB, but only from ServerB itself.   If I try to browse \\ServerB from ServerA, Windows Explorer will attempt to connect for a few seconds and eventually give up.   If I scan both machines using nmap from a remote host, here are the results

[image: ServerA Scanned from my laptop]

[image: ServerB Scanned from my laptop]

As you can see, the only difference between ServerA and ServerB is port 445 is open on ServerA but not ServerB.   The server service is started and running on both systems, and again the firewall is disabled on both machines.   I just need to be able to browse \\ServerB from ServerA and see the shares on ServerB.   It works fine the other way around.   I should also mention both machines are members of a Windows domain, and I am using the same user account on both machines and the account has domain admin access if that matters.   Any idea why one of the two servers is only able to browse the shares locally?

Comment: When you try on the ip of serverb \\1.2.3.4\c$ for example, are you then able to connect or not? If you can try to reboot serverb also, maybe something is pending installation which stops smb.